# Get Json Value within XML - PHP

Tags: php, xml, json

Say I have the following php:

```
$Url = sprintf( "http://www.wowhead.com/item=%u?xml", $EntryId );
$Xml = file_get_contents( $Url );   
//echo htmlentities($Xml, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');     
$Xml = simplexml_load_string( $Xml);
```

and lets say this is the xml:

```
http://www.wowhead.com/item=31065?xml
```

I know if T want say DisplayID I can do:

```
$DisplayId = $Xml->item->icon["displayId"];
```

However I want to get the values within the `<json>` part of the file.

```
<json>
    <![CDATA[
    "armor":464,"classs":4,"displayid":117596,"id":31064,"level":146,"name":"3Hood of         Absolution","reqclass":16,"reqlevel":70,"slot":1,"slotbak":1,"source":[5],"sourcemore":    [{"n":"Tydormu","t":1,"ti":23381}],"specs":[258],"subclass":1
    ]]>
</json>
```

I want to get the `slotbak` value, but I'm unsure how to do it. I did `echo htmlentities($Xml, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');` to ensure I'm getting the xml file fine, and I am. But when I use `json_decode` or `json_encode` it tends to just either return `{ } { } { }` or simply the object and not the value.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` for json_decode to work.

Try this:

```
$json = $Xml->item->json;

$cleanedJson = str_ireplace(array('<![CDATA[', ']]>'), array('{', '}'),  $json);

$jsonObject = json_decode($cleanedJson);
```

Comment: hi thanks for responding. I tried this, pastebin.com/KY9YDqFD
as you suggested, and It returns `NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL`. Any ideas?

Comment: Strangely, I got working by instead doing `$json = "{".$json."}";`. upon closer inspecting despite the cdata tags being on the site, they weren't being added in the variables. The variable was valid json, just without `{` and `}`. Accepting this as the correct answer, thanks!